# Find the maximum rate change.

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find all points from the domain of 
$$
f(x,y)=e^{x^2-xy-1}
$$
in which the function f reaches the maximum rate change (I mean gain/increase) in the direction of x-axis

the domain: (am I right?)
$$
x \in R, y \in R
$$
so the domain is real numbers>0.

I thought about directional derivative and it's property:
$$
[e^{x^2-xy-1}(2x-y), e^{x^2-xy-1}(-x)]*[cos\alpha, cos\beta]
$$
where
$$
cos\alpha=1, cos\beta=0
$$
so it's:
$$
e^{x^2-xy-1}(2x-y)
$$
and what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You now have a function (call this g(x,y)) that gives the rate of change of f in the direction of the x-axis for every point (x,y). The question remains when is g(x,y) a maximum? i.e. when is the rate of change of f in the direction of the x-axis a maximum?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should take the derivative and set it equal to zero to find extrema, to find out if it is a (local) minimum or maximum you should take a look at the second derivative.